# Eigenvalue-like problem for two matrices with coupled blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

For given two real-symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, both are of size $M \times M$, I'm trying to find two matrices $C_1$ (size $M\times N_1$) and $C_2$ (size $M\times N_2$) such that
$$
AC_1 = C_1\Lambda_1 + C_2S^\top\\
BC_2 = C_1S + C_2\Lambda_2
$$
where $\Lambda_1$, $\Lambda_2$ are diagonal matrices of size $N_1 \times N_1$ and $N_2 \times N_2$, respectively. $S$ is a matrix of size $N_1 \times N_2$, $N_1 + N_2 < M$. The column vectors of $C_1$ and $C_2$ are orthonormal, i.e.,
$$
C_1^\top C_1 = I_{N_1N_1}\\
C_2^\top C_2 = I_{N_2N_2}\\
C_1^\top C_2 = 0_{N_1N_2}
$$
If $A$ commutes with $B$, i.e., $AB = BA$, the solution is straightforward, one can diagonalize $A$ or $B$ and use $N_1 + N_2$ number of eigenvectors to construct $C_1$ and $C_2$, in which case $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ correspond to the eigenvalues and $S$ is simply a zero matrix. My question is, if $A$ does not commute with $B$, how to solve for $C_1$ and $C_2$?

This question arises from a constrained optimization problem where I want to find $C_1$ and $C_2$ to minimize the following quantity:
$$
{\rm Tr}(C_1^\top AC_1) + {\rm Tr}(C_2^\top BC_2)
$$
subject to the orthonormality constraints. The Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L} = {\rm Tr}(C_1^\top AC_1) + {\rm Tr}(C_2^\top BC_2) - {\rm Tr}(\Lambda_1(C_1^\top C_1 - I)) - {\rm Tr}(\Lambda_2(C_2^\top C_2 - I)) - {\rm Tr}(S^\top(C_1^\top C_2))
$$
where $\Lambda_1$, $\Lambda_2$, and $S$ are Lagrangian multipliers. The equations in the original question pop up naturally when setting the gradient of $\mathcal{L}$ to zero and realize that the unitary transformation $C_1 \rightarrow C_1U$ does not change Tr$(C_1^\top AC_1)$ (such that $\Lambda_1$ can be made diagonal), and so does it for $C_2$.

I think the question from the optimization view can be harder than solving the linear equations because even in the case where $AB = BA$, one still needs to sort the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ and find a way to pick up the correct states. For this reason, I want to make this post focus mainly on the linear algebra part.

Comment: Going back to the original minimization problem, it might be easier to think of the problem as minimizing the rewritten objective funciton
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A[C_1C_1]^T) + \operatorname{Tr}(B[C_2C_2]^T).
$$
Here, the orthogonality constraints make it so that $P_1 := C_1C_1^T$ and $P_2 := C_2C_2^T$ are orthogonal projections, i.e. they satisfy $P_i = P_i^T = P_i^2$, and so that $P_1 P_2 = P_2P_1 = 0$ (note: $P_1 P_2 = 0 \iff P_2P_1 = 0$). Once $P_1,P_2$ are obtained, $C_1,C_2$ can be easily found with QR decompositions.

Comment: By the way, $N_1$ and $N_2$ are the traces (also the ranks) of $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively

Comment: That's right, I have also tried to formulate the optimization problem in terms of projection operators, in which case the Lagrangian is $\mathcal{L} = {\rm Tr}(AP_1) + {\rm Tr}(BP_2) - {\rm Tr}(\epsilon_1(P_1^2-P_1)) - {\rm Tr}(\epsilon_2(P_2^2-P_2))- {\rm Tr}(\sigma(P_1P_2+P_2P1))$, where $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$, and $\sigma$ are Lagrangian multipliers and are all of size $M \times M$. In the third constraint I used a symmetric form such that I can assume $\sigma$ is symmetric.

Comment: Note that $P_1P_2+P_2P_1 = 0 \iff P_1P_2 = -P_2P_1 \Rightarrow P_1P_2P_1 = -P_2P_1 \iff P_1P_2P_1 = -P_1P_2$, which gives $P_1P_2 = 0$. The corresponding equations are $\\AP_1 = P_1\epsilon_1P_1 + P_2\sigma P_1\\ BP_2 = P_2\epsilon_2P_2 + P_1\sigma P_2\\$ which is similar to the equations in the original post but I still have little clues on how to analyze them...